# Is $f (x)^{f (x)}$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

> Let $f$ be a positive measurable function.Show that $g $ defined by $g (x):= f (x)^{f (x)}$ is measurable.

I have tried my level best though I fail to grasp the problem in my own.Would anybody please help me by giving me some hint that leads to some satisfactory solution.Then that will really help me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Composition of measurable functions is measurable. $f(x)^{f(x)}=e^{f(x) \ln f(x)}$ and $\ln$ and the exponential functions are measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x\rightarrow\ln f(x)^{f(x)}=f(x)\ln f(x)$. Since $f$ is measurable and $\ln$ is continuous, then $\ln f$ is measurable, and so is the multiple $f\ln f$. And then $x\rightarrow\exp(f(x)\ln f(x))$ is measurable by the composition again by the continuous map $\exp$.

Comment: Or simply the composition of $f$ and the continuous function $x\mapsto x^x$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.